# Converting days into weeks in R

Tags: r, date

I want to convert days into weeks with all the values from that week summed up

Right now I have the following `df`

```
          Date  x
1   2018-02-23 15
2   2018-03-26  4
3   2018-03-29  3
4   2018-03-30  6
5   2018-04-03  5
6   2018-04-04 12
7   2018-04-05  7
8   2018-04-06  5
9   2018-04-07  5
10  2018-04-09 13
11  2018-04-10  8
12  2018-04-11  2
```

ETC.

The `x` in this `df` stands for amount of items sent on a certain day.
There are days in this `df` where there are no items beeing transported.
This `df` has a total of `688` tuples.

What I would like to see it:

```
           Date   x
1   Week 8 2018  19
2   Week 9 2018  26
3   Week 10 2018  33
```

ETC.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: How do you define weeks?

Comment: @RonakShah made a small mistake. I editted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` and get the weeks with `format` `%V`:

```
aggregate(df$x, list(Date=format(df$Date, "%V %Y")), sum)
#     Date  x
#1 08 2018 15
#2 13 2018 13
#3 14 2018 34
#4 15 2018 23
```

Or with *Week* (Thanks to @sindri-baldur for the comment):

```
aggregate(df$x, list(Date=sub("^0?", "Week ", format(df$Date, "%V %Y"))), sum)
#aggregate(df$x, list(Date=format(df$Date, "Week %-V %Y")), sum) #Alternative
#          Date  x
#1 Week 13 2018 13
#2 Week 14 2018 34
#3 Week 15 2018 23
#4  Week 8 2018 15
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="          Date  x
1   2018-02-23 15
2   2018-03-26  4
3   2018-03-29  3
4   2018-03-30  6
5   2018-04-03  5
6   2018-04-04 12
7   2018-04-05  7
8   2018-04-06  5
9   2018-04-07  5
10  2018-04-09 13
11  2018-04-10  8
12  2018-04-11  2")
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

Comment: Could also `format(df$Date, "Week %V %Y")`, which matches expected output except for the leading 0.

Comment: Sadly when I use this code I get this answer: Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thanks for the comment! I have included it in the answer.

Comment: @Akula135 Can you provide *Data* where this error happens?

Comment: @GKi See link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16TPY2km5hsLTeH_s77ymcP04yCcKRTvI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There I get "Access Denied" when trying to download the data.

Comment: How about this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/brwjt1pk7x6xyas/Filtered%20Data.csv?dl=0

Comment: I get no error with this data doing: `df <- read.csv("Filtered Data.csv"); df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date); aggregate(df$x, list(Date=format(df$Date, "%V %Y")), sum)`

Comment: It finally worked. I have no idea why it did not work in the first place. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

## Random data
df <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to=as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"),x=runif(n=365,min=0,max=25))


## Aggregating by week
df2 <- df %>%
mutate(week = lubridate::week(ymd(date))) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(total_per_week = sum(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
   ftransform(week = week(ymd(Date))) %>% 
   fgroup_by(week) %>% 
   fsummarise(total_per_week = fsum(x))
#  week total_per_week
#1    8             15
#2   13             13
#3   14             34
#4   15             23
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2018-02-23", "2018-03-26", "2018-03-29", 
"2018-03-30", "2018-04-03", "2018-04-04", "2018-04-05", "2018-04-06", 
"2018-04-07", "2018-04-09", "2018-04-10", "2018-04-11"), x = c(15L, 
4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Answer (score 0):

@akrun
This almost worked. Right now I get 52 rows out of 3 years of data:

```
   week total_per_week
1     1            246
2     2            491
3     3            458
4     4            556
5     5            454
6     6            594
7     7            592
8     8            496
9     9            567
10   10            615
```